# addBlockingEntryWithNextSequentialPhoneNumber barred Apple Store

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, store, callkit

I'm trying to get my app into Apple Store. But the Apple Store Review tells me that i have an reference to 'addBlockingEntryWithNextSequentialPhoneNumber' selector and i have to get rid of it.

So my problem is that i didn't find any reference like this. Does anyone know if this reference is part of a Xamarin package. Ore has anyone another hint for me to solve this issue.

The Apple Review Team and Support couldn't help me.

Any hint would be helpful.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

`addBlockingEntryWithNextSequentialPhoneNumber` is part of `CallKit` and was add to iOS10.

**Assuming you are not submitting a CallKit enabled app**:

- Ensure that your release builds that you are submitting to the App Store have the managed linker **enabled** via `Link Framework SDKs Only` or `Link All` to ensure that CallKit references are properly removed during the link phase.

[image]

**If you are submitting a `CallKit` enabled app**:

- Beware that Apple has placed a hold on reviewing/approving call blocking apps due to security and reliability issues till iOS 10.1(+?) is released.

**Last check**:

- You are including any 3rd party ObjC libraries via Binding projects that are linked to `CallKit`?

Ref: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/blob/fc55e4306f79491fd269ca2495c6a859799cb1c6/src/callkit.cs#L207